# KVL Doubt in circuit

Tags: diodes, kirchhoffs-laws

I am having some doubts regarding the derived KVLs from this circuit where I'm assuming both diodes to be on.
[image: Circuit]

By applying KVL to both loops I got:

```
KVL (I) Vc = R1I + VD1 
KVL (II) Vf = VD2 + R2I2 - VD1
```

However, it seems I got KVL (II) wrong, I think I wrongfully assumed the current direction.
Could someone please clarify KVL (II) for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think you got the second equation wrong?

Comment: *I think I wrongfully assumed the current direction* <-- why?

Comment: Hint:   Assume there's 0.7V across each diode.   There "has" to be (or they're not conducting).   That means point D is at +0.7V above ground.   The diode to ground forces it to be so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused about what to do with Vf because its **value** is negative. I suggest that you explicitly draw an ideal voltage source connected to node F and label it with the appropriate value. This should help you write the correct equation.

Comment: You are right, I was confusing it. Thanks for the help! :)